# I have a question about uploading the node js file

Tags: node.js

I'm going to upload the file through node js There are many ways to upload image files on the Internet. However, there is no way to upload video files or voice files. Is uploading such video files or voice files the same as image files? Do I just put the voice file or video file in the space where the image file goes?

Comment: upload them where? Can you show some code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.